# How could user input be pulled from a text box and previewed in another window?

Tags: html

I am currently doing some web design work for a company, and I've come into an issue I can't solve.

When a customer buys something from my employers site, they have the opportunity to customise text that appears on their product. Is there any way to pull user inputted text and display it in another window?

Comment: This sounds out of the scope of javascript.

Comment: What you mean by 'another window'? Another page? Yes, it is possible, but please provide more details - question is pretty vague...And yes, HTML is not sufficient for this.

Comment: Another window in the browser, yes. I wish I could better describe what I wanted to do, but I'm not eloquent enough when it comes to IT terminology.

Comment: Np - i guess that your employers already use some e-commerce software, and that they want option to customize product, and to show product with user custom text? Something like this: http://www.spreadshirt.com/design-your-own-t-shirt-C59

Comment: Essentially like that, but that is way more than they are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/write-content-dynamic-javascript-popup/), you can open a new window and write whatever contents you want there:

```
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
w.document.write('Content goes here');
w.document.close(); // needed for chrome and safari
```

But beware of popup blockers. I would rather use DIV or IFRAME for that.

Include jQuery in your project and define

```
<div id="previewDiv"></div>
```

somewhere in your markup, then (assuming your text field has id `textField`) call

```
$('#preview').html($('#textField').val());
```

Comment: I see. Do you have any suggestions if I wanted to use IFRAME or DIV?

Comment: Both a 'div' and an 'iframe' are on the same page as the textbox where the user will enter their data. If you go that route (and I would personally prefer going that route btw), I would go for a div. You then send some data to the server, and after the server makes something with it, you'll retrieve the data the server sends back and put it in the div.

Comment: I updated answer with DIV variety. for IFRAME its basically the same, as for popup window, just use `getElementById` to initialise `w` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a hidden `<form action="[preview_url]" target="_blank">` with a hidden input.  When your "preview" button is clicked, copy the textbox's value to the hidden input value, and submit the hidden form.

**Note:** This doesn't degrade gracefully (without javascript), but I suspect no front-end solution would.